# Getting contents of title tags with Python script

Tags: python, mysql, html, sql

I want to make a really script in Python that gets the contents from the title tags of a specified web page and then puts them into a MySQL database.

I have very (and I mean very) little experience with Python but this needs to be done for my project. How can I do this in the simplest way possible?

I hope you are able to understand what I'm trying to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Study [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples) to see how to download the webpage.
2. Study [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) to parse the HTML and pull out the title.
3. Study the [Python Database API Specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) to insert rows into
   the MySQL database.

---

Here is some example code to get you started:

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb

f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(f.read())
title=soup.find('title')
print(title.string)

connection=MySQLdb.connect(
    host='HOST',user='USER',
    passwd='PASS',db='MYDB')
cursor=connection.cursor()

sql='''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
           fooid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (fooid)
       )'''
cursor.execute(sql)

sql='INSERT INTO foo (title) VALUES (%s)'
args=[title.string]
cursor.execute(sql,args)
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: @unbuntu's example code will get you started. `urllib2` is part of Python, but you need to install the other two packages from http://pypi.python.org/pypi

Answer (score 1):

use urllib2 to open up the web page. Then parse the returned text with regex to retrieve the title.

Comment: No. Never try to use __regular__ expressions on HTML, it's not __regular__. Also, as the poster said they had no Python experience, this is completely unhelpful even if it was right.